# Declaring ranges from different sheets as public variables to use them in many subs

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file with 10 sheets. In my module i have one sub and in it i set same ranges of every sheet with a name (fe myrange1 = sheet1.range("A1:A10") etc)
I want now to cut my sub into more than 1.
Is there a way to set all this ranges to public so i wont have to repeat this in every sub?

Comment: Why not writing a funktion with sheetname as Parameter?

Comment: Sorry everyone: public mysheet as worksheet

Comment: thanks for your time ruedi. I did that too works ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry everyone: public mysheet as worksheet

found it my mistake. I was trying public mysheet as sheets and was getting error